# Find duplicates with aggregation and lookup with MongoDB and Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I need to find duplicates with aggregation and lookup with MongoDB and Golang.
Here is my `Event` structure.

```
// Event describes the model of an Event
type Event struct {
    ID            string      `bson:"_id" json:"_id" valid:"alphanum,printableascii"`
    OldID         string      `bson:"old_id" json:"old_id" valid:"alphanum,printableascii"`
    ParentID      string      `bson:"_parent_id" json:"_parent_id" valid:"alphanum,printableascii"`
    Name          string      `bson:"name" json:"name"`
    Content       string      `bson:"content" json:"content"`
    Slug          string      `bson:"slug" json:"slug"`
    LocationID    string      `bson:"_location_id" json:"_location_id"`
    Price         string      `bson:"price" json:"price"`
    CreatedBy     string      `bson:"created_by" json:"created_by"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time   `bson:"created_at" json:"created_at"`
    ModifiedAt    time.Time   `bson:"modified_at" json:"modified_at"`
}
```

Here is the request I already have :

```
// Create the pipeline
    pipeline := []bson.M{
        bson.M{
            "$group": bson.M{
                "_id": bson.M{
                    "_location_id": "$_location_id",
                    "start_date":   "$start_date",
                },
                "docs":  bson.M{"$push": "$_id"},
                "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1},
            },
        },
        bson.M{
            "$match": bson.M{
                "count": bson.M{"$gt": 1.0},
            },
        },
    }

    // Do the request
    dupes := []bson.M{}
    err := session.DB(shared.DatabaseNamespace).C(dao.collection).Pipe(pipeline).All(&dupes)
```

The events must not have the same **start_date** and the same **_location_id**.
This is what I can get :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "_location_id" : "4okPZllaoueYC3U2",
        "start_date" : ISODate("2018-04-22T18:00:00.000Z")
    },
    "count" : 2.0,
    "docs" : [ 
        "FFSC2sJcrWgj2FsU", 
        "lwHknTHFfVAzB8ui"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "_location_id" : "pC8rlLVao5c2CeBh",
        "start_date" : ISODate("2018-04-03T19:00:00.000Z")
    },
    "count" : 2.0,
    "docs" : [ 
        "jPRbkINiCExzh2tT", 
        "C8hx92QSZEl7HUIz"
    ]
}
```

Fine, it is working, but..
I would like to obtain, directly from Mongo, an array of my Event type, and if it is possible, an array of array of Event : `[][]*Event`.
In order words, an array of the duplicates (between them).

For example :

```
// Pipeline
...

// Do the request
events := [][]*Events
err := session.DB(shared.DatabaseNamespace).C(dao.collection).Pipe(pipeline).All(&events)
```

Or, do I need to perform the logic with Golang to achieve what I need ?

The libraries I use are :

```
"gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
"gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
```

Note only : no need to take care about the `_location_id`, I lookup it with a DTO inside my Golang logic.

**EDIT** : If I cannot lookup the IDs, can I at least obtain the IDs as an array directly in the result ? For example :

```
[ 
    "jPRbkINiCExzh2tT", 
    "C8hx92QSZEl7HUIz"
]
```

This is what I tried to add to the request : `{$out: "uniqueIds"}`. But it is not working.

Comment: few ways. 1. you can return duplicates from query 2. you can make a hashmap and have a 'count' parameter in that hashmap value. This depends on the complexity of the query and how scalable is your DB vs application layer and to whom this is needed for. if having duplicates breaks the app, you should also look into adding a unique constraint

Comment: @tsuz : Actually I need to return the duplicates directly from Mongo in order to do not have an logic to perform in Golang, if it is possible of course, that was my question, that is why I need help for..

Comment: But for non-duplicates, you want to perform some operation? In that case, I'd generate an array of Event (or a Events where it's []Event) which contains at least `location_id` and `start_date`. After data accessing layer, if you know you're only going to perform the duplicates check once, you could make a structure like `map[string][time.Time]*Event` where the string is location ID and time.Time is the start time. Then it's a duplicate if Event is not nil. You also do this immutably by creating a method on `Events` struct like `func (e *Events) generateUniq`

Comment: No I just want to find the duplicates, I want to Mongo to return me an "array of duplicates" directly : `[][]*Events`. Each item of the array is an array of the events that are duplicated.

Comment: Well, either way, the approach is you'd have to look up all `Event`s and use some structure like `map[string][time.Time]` to determine duplicates and create another list to store the duplicates to return. If the ratio of duplicates to total is very low, I'd suggest filtering on the query.

Comment: @tsuz : I already have a request (see above), instead of what I have, I need Mongo to return directly what I need, array of array of Events. Is that possible ? If yes, what is the request ?

Comment: @tsuz : May I ask help to have the full Mongo request please ?

Comment: Have you tried using [bson.D](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#D)?

Comment: @tsuz : not at all !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to perform the logic with Golang to achieve what you need.

You can do like this :

```
    type DublesAgregate struct {
    Id        IdStruct        `bson:"_id"`
    Docs      []bson.ObjectId `bson:"docs"`
    Count     string          `bson:"count,omitempty"`
}

type IdStruct struct {
    Location_id      string `bson:"_location_id,omitempty"`
    Start_date       string `bson:"start_date,omitempty"`
}

// Create the pipeline
    pipeline := []bson.M{
        bson.M{
            "$group": bson.M{
                "_id": bson.M{
                    "_location_id": "$_location_id",
                    "start_date":   "$start_date",
                },
                "docs":  bson.M{"$push": "$_id"},
                "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1},
            },
        },
        bson.M{
            "$match": bson.M{
                "count": bson.M{"$gt": 1.0},
            },
        },
    }

// Do the request
    dupes := []DublesAgregate{}
    err := session.DB(shared.DatabaseNamespace).C(dao.collection).Pipe(pipeline).All(&dupes)

// Get Docs slice
    result := []bson.ObjectId{}
    for _, group := range dupes {
        result = append(result, group.Docs...)
    }
```